# Python Regex Findall non-greedy

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am relatively new to regex and I seem to be struggling to understand the greedy vs non-greedy search (if that is indeed the issue here). Let's say I have a simple text such as this:

> # numbers: 4 A 3 B

My goal would be to run a findall to get something like the following output:

> ['# number:', '4 A 3 B', ' 4 A', ' 3 B']

So if I use the following regex with findall, I would expect it to work:

```
matches = re.findall(r"(# numbers:)(((?:\s\d)(?:\s\D))*)", "# numbers: 4 A 3 B")
```

However, the actual output is this:

> [('# numbers:', ' 4 A 3 B', ' 3 B')]

Can someone explain why the group ((\s\d)(\d\D)) is only matching ' 3 B' and not also ' 4 A'? I assume it has something to do with the greedy vs. non-greedy search of * is that true? And if so, could you explain how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `re.findall` here, twice.  First, extract the digit/non digit text series, then use `re.findall` a second time to find the tuples:

```py
inp = "# numbers: 4 A 3 B"
text = re.findall(r'^# numbers:\s+(.*)$', inp)[0]
matches = re.findall(r'(\d+)\s+(\D+)', text)
print(matches)  # [('4', 'A '), ('3', 'B')]
```

Comment: thanks for the idea! I thought about that too, but I am wondering why the first solution isn't working. I would have assumed that any group is searched and returned if found in "findall". Why only the last, do you know?

Comment: You used: `(((?:\s\d)(?:\s\D))*)`  ... this places the entire repeat pattern into a single capture group, and Python's regex engine only "remember" the very last match.

Comment: I see and do you know if there is no way to have the repeat pattern be "remembered" for each time it is found?

Comment: Your current approach is not salvagable AFAIK, hence my workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I still don't understand why re.findall(r'(\d+)\s+(\D+)', text) finds all patterns, but re.findall(r'(\d+)\s+(\D+)*', text) (with *) does not. Also re.findall(r'(\d+)\s+(\D+)*?', text) (with *?) seems to work as will. Strange